# Is it possible to make a css declaration override a style set in the element's style property?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a css declaration override a style set in the element's style property?

eg:

```
<div class="root"><p style="font-size:13px;">hello</p></div>
```

Is there someway I can override the font size with css?

I already tried `.root p{font-size:16px !important;}`

The reason I want to do this is that I am making a javascript rich text editor, and sometimes when someone pastes into the editor, it adds styles like that.  But I don't want it to appear as smaller text.

Comment: `!important` should work - I think, anyway :D Which browser are you using to test?

Comment: `!important` should work in everything except for IE6 and below.  That's how *I* override inline styles.

Comment: You shouldn't have a class on the closing `div` tag.  That's invalid.

Comment: um, your example with `!important` actually **does work**: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/ddweb/

Comment: are you ok to use javascript ?? if so we can easily do with jquery.

Comment: I retried it. It works in chrome and firefox, but doesn't work in IE8, until I press enter inside the content that was just pasted.  @sebastian - yep, works when the content is static, but in my scenario, the content is being added by someone pasting it in a contentEditable div, maybe IE is having some problem updating styles when that happens or something.

Comment: @stephen - Why shouldn't I have a class on the div tag?

Comment: Try this:  `<div class="root"><p style="font-size:13px;">hello</p></div>`
   
http://jsfiddle.net/8qUBu/

Comment: @Kyle: You *can* have a class on the div tag.  Just not redeclared on the closing part of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code looks wrong , remove the class=root on closing div.

```
<div class="root"><p style="font-size:13px;">hello</p></div class="root">
```

with jquery you can do it as below

fontsize can be a variable which you set dynamically

```
('selector').css('font-size',fontsize);
```

Comment: I'm really confused, why shouldn't I have a class on the div? It is how I know that that div is the root of my rich text editor.

Comment: You should not have it on the _closing_ tag; that's not how HTML works.

Comment: @domenic - oh, haha, didn't notice that, was too quick with my copy pasting. Yea, my real code doesn't have that.

Comment: @kyle , thats fine then , can you overwrite with jquery or javascript??is that approach ok

Comment: @gov - Unfortunately I can't edit the elements with javascript because once you do that, the rich text editor loses it's undo/redo history in IE. I think the css solution is good enough since it works in firefox and chrome though.

Comment: @gov - I actually just tried it and it worked fine! I guess undo/redo only gets messed up if you change the html structure or something, but simply changing an attribute is fine :)